# crystal reports labels creeping up page

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I utilized the Crystal Reports wizard to create the template for Avery 5260 labels. I have up to 6 rows that can be printed on a label. For the details of rows 2 to 6 I put in a suppress if the field in the row is blank or null because I don't want the blank row on the label. The font is Ariel 9. By the (2) row of labels you can see that the text is beginning to creep up the label and by row (4) it is out of the label.
I am using the current version of CR for VS 2010 (CRforVS_13_0_4).
Any assistance in rectifying this situation is appreciated.

Comment: Are the rows creeping up because you're suppressing blank rows?

Comment: Even if I remove the suppress if blank, by the 4th row I am printing outside the top of the label. I created another report where I placed all the fields within a single detail section, that indicated it was 1 inch in height, the same as the label, but that also would creep outside the label by the 4th row.